# How to make remote secured web call from Windows 2003 server ASP

Tags: asp-classic

How can I make this kind of code for Windows 2003 IIS server?

```
Dim req as New WebClient()

Dim myCache As New CredentialCache()
myCache.Add(New Uri(URL), "Basic", _
            New NetworkCredential(Username, Password))

req.Credentials = myCache

Dim results as String 
results = System.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req.DownloadData(URL))
```

Comment: That's because the code you have there looks more like VB.NET, not VBScript.

Comment: Is there similar solution for VBScript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself, this VBScript code makes a call to url  with user:pass credentials, the base64 class is required due the bug in ms library.

```
Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
dim url
url = "any.html"
http.open "GET", url,  False,"user","pass"
http.setRequestHeader "Authorization",  "Basic " & Base64Encode("user:pass")
http.send
```

> Function Base64Encode(inData) 'ripped from: 
>   'http://www.pstruh.cz/tips/detpg_Base64Encode.htm   'rfc1521   '2001
>   Antonin Foller, PSTRUH Software, http://pstruh.cz   Const Base64 = _
>   "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
>   Dim sOut, I
>        'For each group of 3 bytes   For I = 1 To Len(inData) Step 3
>       Dim nGroup, pOut
>
> ```
> 'Create one long from this 3 bytes.
> nGroup = &H10000 * Asc(Mid(inData, I, 1)) + _
>   &H100 * MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 1, 1)) + _
>   MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 2, 1))
>
> 'Oct splits the long To 8 groups with 3 bits
> nGroup = Oct(nGroup)
>
> 'Add leading zeros
> nGroup = String(8 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup
>
> 'Convert To base64
> pOut = Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
>   Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
>   Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
>   Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 7, 2)) + 1, 1)
>
> 'Add the part To OutPut string
> sOut = sOut + pOut
>    Next   Select Case Len(inData) Mod 3
> Case 1: '8 bit final
>   sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 2) + "=="
> Case 2: '16 bit final
>   sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 1) + "="   
>     End Select   Base64Encode = sOut End Function
> ```

Comment: Not the best answer, no explanation also you've included a reference to `Base64Encode()` function but don't provide the source for other users. Consider improving the answer not just for yourself but for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could compile this to a [webservice using VB.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301273) and make calls to it [using SOAP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20125/Using-SOAP-With-Classic-ASP-VBScript) from your classic ASP site.

You may find that you'd need to extend the functionality of the service to include other facilities to manipulate your requirements later on.

This probably isn't the best solution, but it's something to consider.